# How to fetch the data from a helper class

Tags: c#

`Consider the input of the program as “inputObject” and you have a helper class with the name “objectService”. When you call any function from objectService helper class it will fetch the data from the database maintaining the output as multiple objects with same author. Fill the code in the Result function to perform the output using the details given below.

Below is my code`

```
inputObjects = [{id:1, idAuthor: 1, name: null, author: null}]


objectService {
    // This function fetch an object from the database
    // Input id is the id of the Object which you fetch data from database 
    Object Read(int id)
    // This function fetch objects from the database
    // Input ids are the ids of the Objects which you fetch data from database
    List<Object> Read(List<int> ids)
}


class Object {
    int id;
    string name;
}


outputObjects = [{id:1, idAuthor: 1, name: "Object name", author: "author name"}]
private void Result (List<Object> objects) {
      // Complete the code
}
```

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. Please explain what you have tried and what is not working for you.

Comment: I am new to this. I want to know how to get the output as mentioned. I tried calling creating a object of helper class and calling   the read method

Comment: `I tried calling creating a object of helper class and calling the read method` and what happened? what issue did you encounter?

Comment: outputObjects = [{id:1, idAuthor: 1, name: "Object name", author: "author name"}]

How to get the output as this